# How to use Azure DevOps API to autocomplete a pull request for “rebase and fast-forward” merge type?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have two main branches in my repo: master and production. The feature branches merge to master and there is a pipeline which uses REST API to create PRs to push changes from master to production. I want to keep history of master and production exact same, so I only allow "Rebase and fast-forward" merge type in production branch. Everything works fine except the fact that I cannot auto-complete the PR using Azure DevOps Rest API.

I am following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#gitpullrequestcompletionoptions) to auto-complete the PR but there is only squashMerge option here. Is there support for other type of merges (Rebase and fase-forward or Rebase with merge commit) using REST APT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Rest API version 5.1 (in preview) you have the option to `completionOptions`, it's contains `GitPullRequestCompletionOptions` and there you have `mergeStrategy`:

- noFastForward
- rebase
- rebaseMerge
- squash

See the Docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#gitpullrequestmergestrategy).

Put attention that you need to use this version in the URL: `api-version=5.1`